# My salesforce simulator is not working properly for salesforce1 it is showing me classic view

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce-classic, salesforce-support

I login on salesforce simulator but it gives me a classic view and I want to get a mobile view. how can i get.

For reference, I have attached the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce retired the mobile web experience with the Summer '20 release. You can read the Knowledge Article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349471&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).

As per now I do not think that you are able to test your developments emulating the mobile app on Chrome/SF1 Simulator, even though they said that simulator builds of the Salesforce mobile app would be available to download.

Best regards!