# Why Mobile Debugging does not work on MacOS13/XCode14/iOS16.4? Why no inspectable apps are shown in Safaris Develop-Menu?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, debugging, salesforce-mobile-app

After a long journey I was able to find out how to get a CSS-Inspector for iOS. I have answered my own question for that here:

[How to Run and Debug Salesforce Mobile App on the desktop? (reloaded 3rd time and many years later...)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404639/how-to-run-and-debug-salesforce-mobile-app-on-the-desktop-reloaded-3rd-time-an)

It's not perfect but at least it works and it looks like this

[image]

Now I've clamped my teeth an bought a new Mac Mini for my team mate and want the exact same setup to get the exact same outcome: a simple CSS Inspector for iOS!

But no luck...

It just looks like this

[image]

Safari > Develop > Simulator can not find any inspectable app on the new Mac Mini, while it found 3 on the old MacBook. I usually inspect the "bridge.app" which provides me exactly what I need?

The key specs are

**Old MacBookPro 2018 (Intel)**

- MacOS 12
- XCode 13
- Simulated iOS 15.5

**New MacMini 2023 (M2)**

- MacOS 13.2
- XCode 14.3.1 (on 2023-06 most recent except beta)
- Simulated iOS 16

The Salesforce app is exactly the same on both systems. It is downloaded here https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/mobile-debugging

What have I done wrong? Why Safari does not finding any inspectable app? Do I need to throw the Mac Mini into the trash and go buy a new more vintage Mac to replicate the setup which I need and I got already on my old MacBook?

All that Salesforce Mobile Development is so overcomplicated with this toolchain, not easy to setup, error prone, version sensitive, fragile, and time consuming.

I would appreciate any hint or help how to make Safari find inspectable apps of the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out by trial-and-error. The reason was XCode version 14.3.1, which is at the time of writing (2023-06-29) the most recent version.

14.3.1. does not provide any inspectable apps

Downgraded to 14.0.1...

14.0.1. works just as on my old MacBookPro. This is a version hell...

I think I also found out **why** it is not working. XCode 14.3.1 provides iOS 16.4 in the simulator. Now there is a new "feature" which might be very nasty: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1301

> Since iOS 16.4, the webview has to be marked as "inspectable" to
> enable the functionality of web inspection.

Likely this "feature" is newer that Salesforce "Chatter.app" they provide us for mobile development. Hence the option is not enabled and nothing is inspectabel.

**Salesforce please! Provide a new Chatter.app which is inspectable!**