# Why Mobile Debugging does not work on MacOS13/XCode14.0.1/iOS16.0? Why NO simulator is shown in Safaris Develop-Menu?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, debugging, salesforce-mobile-app

I wasted already hours to solve this "feature" here: [Why Mobile Debugging does not work on MacOS13/XCode14/iOS16.4? Why no inspectable apps are shown in Safaris Develop-Menu?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/406300/why-mobile-debugging-does-not-work-on-macos13-xcode14-ios16-4-why-no-inspectabl)

Now today I wanted to dive into debugging but: surprise, surprise! Now NO simulators AT ALL are shown anymore in the darn Safari > Develop menu. I can't remember that I have changed anything since my last successful run with XCode 14.0.1 Simulator and iOS 16.0

The effect is different to:

- the earlier issue had shown all the simulators I have started but NO inspectable app.

  - This old issue is solved already by downgrading to XCode 14.0.1 (iOS 16.0) which does not need a webview has to be marked as "inspectable" (which Salesforce is very likely not doing in the Chatter.app provided by them for mobile debugging)
- the current issue does NOT show ANY simulators I start in Safari. Simply nothing at all.

Research on Google brought only old crap dating back year ago pointing me to use the Technology Preview of Safari.

**Why Safari just stops from on day to another to show any Simulators in the Develop menu?**

**EDIT 1**

This again is horrible for Windows users...

I solved it by uninstalling any versions of XCode and reinstalling 14.0.1. I still had 14.3.1 and 14.0.1 in parallel. Which worked fine last Friday.

I've renamed both XCode versions in the Application folder from just XCode to

- XCode_14_0_1
- XCode_14_3_1

Now after uninstall/reinstall I came up again with a plain "XCode" not having any version-suffix.

- I have no idea if possible, but could this renaming kill the debuggability in Safari?
- Is the parallel installation of two XCode versions an issue?

Maybe my solution is non-permanent and volatile. Therefore I will not post this as an answer and wait for some qualified Salesforce+Apple developers to clear up this mess.

Any ideas are welcome! I would like to understand how this fragile toolchain is supposed to work...